# My echo command for new line is not working

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

My objective is to create a file using the echo command and then transfer it to the remote server, but my echo command is not working.

Here is my code for the echo commands :

```
import os
os.system("echo 'listen {0} '\n' Documentroot '{1}/{2}' '\n' <Directory '{1}'> \n Required all granted' '\n' </Directory>' > /root/Desktop/{3}".format(user_port , user_directory , user_folder , file_name))
```

Comment: Does it work if you try it in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system-wide echo usually needs option `-e` to interpret backslash sequences: `/bin/echo -e "hello\nworld"`.

Trying this in your shell with `echo` might work without option `-e` but will just invoke the shell-builtin whereas your python script will invoke the system-wide echo instead. Both can have different options and behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just print using Python, then pipe it to where it needs to go?

Script

```
print("""listen {0}
Documentroot '{1}/{2}'
... 
""".format(...))
```

Command

```
python script.py > /root/Desktop/output
```